# nullpointerexception at getCount() method

Tags: android

I want to populate listview from database using a cursoradapter. I am getting a NullPointerException caused at getCount method.

thank you in advance :D

Below is my code for Cursor Adapter.

```
public class tasksCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

Cursor cursor;

public tasksCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    this.cursor = c;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    return retView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return cursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(context);
    tasksDatabaseOperations.getWritableDatabase();
    TextView tvTask, tvDate, tvTime;
    tvTask = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_added);
    tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_added);
    tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_added);
    tvTask.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    tvDate.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    tvTime.setText(cursor.getString(3));

}
}
```

And this is where i m implementing the adapter

```
public class tasksListFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

ListView taskslist;
Button delete;
Cursor cursor;

tasksCursorAdapter adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_list_frag, container, false);
    Log.d("HirakDebug", "tasksListFrag View Created");
    taskslist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);
    adapter = new tasksCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY);
    taskslist.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: So, where are you instantiating your `tasksCursorAdapter` and what is the `Cursor` you pass in at that point?

Comment: Add a log in your constructor and verify if the value that gets assigned to the cursor is not null

Comment: when is tasksCursorAdapter used? error log in logcat, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> adapter = new tasksCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY);
> ```

Your `cursor` is not initialized here and it is `null`. A `CursorAdapter` needs an actual `Cursor`.

Comment: what exactly should i do?

Comment: Do a query that returns a `Cursor` before instantiating the adapter.

Comment: yupp.... i figured out i was not actually calling any query. so silly :p. thank u :D

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor should be null. Instead of using an custom defined `cursor` you should use the built in cursor. Remove the `Cursor` declaration in your class and also `this.cursor = c;`. Also remove the overriding of `getCount`. Then it should work normally, that is because `CursorAdapter` by default has a cursor implemented and that is why its called `cursoradapter`.  Just make sure your cursor has some rows

Comment: Are you sure what you are answering?

Comment: yes, take a look at the CursorAdapter.java in the source code of android

Comment: i did what u sayed. Now i am not getting any error, but my listview doesnt show anything after adding data. I updated my question and i have included the code in which cursor adapter is implemented

Comment: are you intializing the cursor??

Comment: first initlise your cursor by making a query and then set it to the adapter

Comment: yup... i figured out i was not actually reading data with my cursor. so silly :p. thank u anyways